# Histogram with Markers, Marker Nodes and Legend Not Displaying Everything Correctly

Tags: nodes, legend, histogram, mark

I am still kinda new to TEX. I am currently working on a paper submission, however I am having trouble properly combining markers, node labels for the markers, a legend and a histogram all in the same graph. This is very easy to do in MATLAB, but not so much in TEX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend entries={$\textit{my}_{data}$,$\textit{sigma}_{3}$,$\textit{testpoint}+2$,$\textit{testpoint}+1$,$\textit{testpoint}$},
    ymin=0, ymax=300,
    minor y tick num = 4,
    %ybar,
    legend style={align=left}
    %legend pos=outer north
    ]
\addlegendimage{ybar interval, fill=blue!30, draw=blue}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=o}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=square*}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=diamond*}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=triangle*}

%histogram plot
\addplot+[ybar interval,mark=no, fill=blue!30,draw=blue] plot coordinates { (-.71, 1) (-.705,0)(-.68,0)(-.675, 1) (-.67, 1) (-.665, 4) (-.66, 5) (-.655, 11)(-.65,34)(-.645,62)(-.64,80)(-.635,108)(-.63,182)(-.625,236)(-.62,220)(-.615,261)(-.61,193)(-.605,143)(-.6,99)(-.595,57)(-.59,20)(-.585,10)(-.58,1)(-.575,0)(-.56,0)(-.555,1)(-.55,1)};

%sigma
\addplot[only marks,mark=o,mark size=2pt,black,nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=4]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        point meta=x,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=30pt},
        ]  coordinates {
    (-.6609,0)
};

%testpoint +2
\addplot[only marks,mark=square*,mark size=2pt,black,nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=4]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        point meta=x,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=30pt},
        ]  coordinates {
    (-.6721,0)
};

%testpoint +1
\addplot[only marks,mark=diamond*,mark size=2pt,black,nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=4]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        point meta=x,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=30pt},
        ]  coordinates {
    (-.7059,0)
};

%testpoint
\addplot[only marks,mark=triangle*,mark size=2pt,black,nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=4]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        point meta=x,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=30pt},
        ]  coordinates {
    (-.5529,0)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example Distribution}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The issue I am having is that when I use the current code, it doesn't show the data bins in the legend properly. On the flip-side, if I include `ybar` in the `axis` options, it messes up the nodes labeling the x coordinate of the markers and makes the markers in the legend doubled.

Any idea how to fix this but still have only 1 legend?

Comment: I was not aware I could use MatLab code in LaTeX. I have updated the code snippet as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ybar interval legend` to the plot options and/or the `\addlegendimage`. (I don't quite understand why you use `\addlegendimage`, it doesn't seem to be needed.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz which loads graphicx
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend entries={$\textit{my}_{data}$,$\textit{sigma}_{3}$,$\textit{testpoint}+2$,$\textit{testpoint}+1$,$\textit{testpoint}$},
    ymin=0, ymax=300,
    minor y tick num = 4,
    %ybar,
    legend style={align=left},
    legend pos=north west,
    legend cell align=left
    ]
%\addlegendimage{ybar interval, ybar interval legend, fill=blue!30, draw=blue}
%\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=o}
%\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=square*}
%\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=diamond*}
%\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=triangle*}

%histogram plot
\addplot [ybar interval,ybar interval legend,fill=blue!30,draw=blue] coordinates { (-.71, 1) (-.705,0)(-.68,0)(-.675, 1) (-.67, 1) (-.665, 4) (-.66, 5) (-.655, 11)(-.65,34)(-.645,62)(-.64,80)(-.635,108)(-.63,182)(-.625,236)(-.62,220)(-.615,261)(-.61,193)(-.605,143)(-.6,99)(-.595,57)(-.59,20)(-.585,10)(-.58,1)(-.575,0)(-.56,0)(-.555,1)(-.55,1)};

%sigma
\addplot[only marks,mark=o,mark size=2pt,black,nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=4]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        point meta=x,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=30pt},
        ]  coordinates {
    (-.6609,0)
};

%testpoint +2
\addplot[only marks,mark=square*,mark size=2pt,black,nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=4]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        point meta=x,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=30pt},
        ]  coordinates {
    (-.6721,0)
};

%testpoint +1
\addplot[only marks,mark=diamond*,mark size=2pt,black,nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=4]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        point meta=x,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=30pt},
        ]  coordinates {
    (-.7059,0)
};

%testpoint
\addplot[only marks,mark=triangle*,mark size=2pt,black,nodes near coords = \rotatebox{90}{{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=4]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        point meta=x,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=30pt},
        ]  coordinates {
    (-.5529,0)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example Distribution}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to work, however there are some weird issues that arise from your version of the code. Adding `ybar interval legend` was the key and only thing necessary in finalizing the plot properly. Including `legend pos` doesn't seem to function for me (throws a "pos does not exist" error) and removing `no markers' from the ybar plot for the histogram adds unnecessary dots/markers.

Comment: @Midimistro Don't know about the `legend pos` thing, there isn't a comma missing or something after `north west`? What exactly does the error say? For the last part, note I removed the `+` in `\addplot +[...`, which means that the options in the brackets overwrite the default ones, instead of appending to them. (Sorry, should have described the changes in the code a bit more.)